# Webservice refuses to run and returns 404 under Eclipse + Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

Consider the Webservice :

```
package com.mcnz.restful.java.example;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ScoreService {
    // localhost:8080/Soccer/score
    @GET
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getScore() {
        String pattern = "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
        return String.format(pattern,  Score.WINS, Score.LOSSES, Score.TIES );  
    }


    // localhost:8080/Soccer/score?wins=2%losses=3@ties=15
    @PUT
    @Path("/score")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String update(@QueryParam("wins") int wins, 
                              @QueryParam("losses") int losses, 
                              @QueryParam("ties")   int ties) {
        Score.WINS   = wins;
        Score.TIES   = ties;
        Score.LOSSES = losses;
        String pattern = "{ \"wins\":\"%s\", \"losses\":\"%s\", \"ties\": \"%s\"}";
        return String.format(pattern,  Score.WINS, Score.LOSSES, Score.TIES );

    }

}
```

With the file structure :

[image]

When I start the project and hit Chrome under :

```
localhost:8080/Soccer/score
```

or

```
localhost:8080/Soccer/score?wins=2%losses=3@ties=15
```

I get :

[image]

What am I doing wrong ? Why do I get a 404 and not the JSONs from the endpoints ?

Comment: Which JAX-RS library are you using? There's usually some setup required before you can just start adding annotations.

Comment: @nitind: `import javax.ws.rs.*;`

Comment: Those are the standard packages and interfaces for declaring your endpoints, but what library are you using to actually process them? You have to be using Wink, or Jersey, or something else as well.

Comment: Tomcat does not have support for JAX-RS out of the box.  Take a look at something like [this tutorial](https://www.theserverside.com/video/Use-Tomcat-Eclipse-to-create-a-JAX-RS-REST-web-service) or use a server like Wildfly that supports it out of the box.